# What tree is this

Tags: identification, trees

Can you help me identify this tree?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be either Beech or Fagus sylvatica...

[image]

See also [search results for "fagus sylvatica flowers" on Yahoo images](https://images.search.yahoo.com/images/view;_ylt=AwrWnajn0eNaeRIAEYWJzbkF;_ylu=X3oDMTIyNjVwZWRkBHNlYwNzcgRzbGsDaW1nBG9pZAM0YTUwNGUxZWI0NzBiY2FhNGJjMDEyYTZlMzU5NmQ3OQRncG9zAzkEaXQDYmluZw--?.origin=&back=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.search.yahoo.com%2Fsearch%2Fimages%3Fp%3Dfagus%2Bsylvatica%2Bflowers%26fr%3Dmcafee%26fr2%3Dpiv-web%26tab%3Dorganic%26ri%3D9&w=1600&h=1042&imgurl=3.bp.blogspot.com%2F-51LBYj1Xci0%2FUgNNIdVQGGI%2FAAAAAAAABFc%2FNyN-ru_RQho%2Fs1600%2FFagus%2Bsylvatica%2B%2525E2%252580%252593%2BEuropean%2BBeech%2B08.jpg&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Ftreesplanet.blogspot.com%2F2013%2F09%2Ffagus-sylvatica-european-beech.html&size=275.3KB&name=Trees%20Planet%3A%20%3Cb%3EFagus%3C%2Fb%3E%20%3Cb%3Esylvatica%3C%2Fb%3E%20%E2%80%93%20European%20Beech&p=fagus%20sylvatica%20flowers&oid=4a504e1eb470bcaa4bc012a6e3596d79&fr2=piv-web&fr=mcafee&tt=Trees%20Planet%3A%20%3Cb%3EFagus%3C%2Fb%3E%20%3Cb%3Esylvatica%3C%2Fb%3E%20%E2%80%93%20European%20Beech&b=0&ni=21&no=9&ts=&tab=organic&sigr=12b76bo76&sigb=13efe9733&sigi=13u03ahp4&sigt=11ug16qi8&sign=11ug16qi8&.crumb=ExIUryJEfn0&fr=mcafee&fr2=piv-web).

Comment: Whoa, I didn't expect this label as an essay either!

Comment: I'd suggest the URL to the page containing that image instead http://treesplanet.blogspot.com/2013/09/fagus-sylvatica-european-beech.html

Comment: I fixed an extremely long link and embedded an image.